# How can I "move" a tag on a file with Subeclipse?

Tags: java, svn, subclipse

I have created a tag with subeclipse :

```
Team > Branch/Tag...
```

I have changed a file and I want this file to be part of the tag I have just created.

I have tried to recreate the same tag but subeclipse refuses because the tag already exists.

How can I delete and recreate the tag with the changed file ?

OR

How can I "move" the tag on the changed file ? (I have a CVS background)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this on the command-line since branches/tags have a special semantic in subclipse.

A tag in SVN is just another "directory" in the repository with a copy of the files. So you could just remove the tag and recreate it (`svn remove`) or copy the new file into the tag's location (`svn copy`).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, it is possible to go on the `SVN Repositories` view. Here I delete my wrong tag and then recreate it from `Team > Branch/Tag...`